# Quarkus - Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy

I'm trying to iterate over a List<Supplier<Stream<TSRecord>>> (connection to the datasource) but processing one stream takes a few minutes so when the program gets to the second element of the list it already throws a "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out".
Does anyone have an idea how to close the streams manually? Just setting the timeout higher will not fix the issue (I think) because the length of the list can vary a lot.

In the old version of the project CloseableService from glassfish was used to deal with the issue but this doesn't work with Quarkus. Quarkus has QuarkusBuildCloseablesBuildItem but as I understood BuildItems are used to create new extensions. RestEasy has ResteasyContext which uses Autocloseables but I don't know if Quarkus uses RestEasy for the Connection to the datasource and if so how to use ResteasyContext to fix the issue.

The class where the error is thrown (line 35 , 37 are the try-blocks):

```
class ZipStreamer implements StreamingOutput {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamingOutput.class);
    private final Iterable<Supplier<StreamAndName<TSRecord>>> streamSuppliers;

    private final TimeResolution resolution;
    private final Set<Parameter> parameters;

    ZipStreamer(final Iterable<Supplier<StreamAndName<TSRecord>>> streamSuppliers, TimeResolution resolution, Set<Parameter> parameters) {
        this.streamSuppliers = streamSuppliers;
        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(output)) {
            for (Supplier<StreamAndName<TSRecord>> sup : streamSuppliers) {
                try (final StreamAndName<TSRecord> next = sup.get()) {
                    LOGGER.debug("Writing entry: {}", next.name());
                    final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(next.name().concat(".csv"));
                    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                    final CsvStreamingOutput so = new CsvStreamingOutput(parameters, resolution, next.stream());
                    so.write(zos);
                } finally {
                    zos.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream$read.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.convertStreamToByteArray(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:477)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.charsetToString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:529)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl$charsetToString$3.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:190)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:180)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:234)
    at io.restassured.response.ResponseBodyData$asString.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at io.restassured.internal.support.Prettifier.getPrettifiedBodyIfPossible(Prettifier.groovy:44)
    at io.restassured.internal.print.ResponsePrinter.print(ResponsePrinter.java:65)
    at io.restassured.filter.log.StatusCodeBasedLoggingFilter.filter(StatusCodeBasedLoggingFilter.java:115)
    at io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter.filter(ResponseLoggingFilter.java:31)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter.filter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:146)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1686)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1692)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:180)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at server.api.ProjectionDataResourceTest.testPostEnsembleDownload(ProjectionDataResourceTest.java:105)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:997)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:816)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

2023-02-10 21:17:06,031 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to %s failed, error id: %s [Error Occurred After Shutdown]: org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server hat keine Antwort zurückgegeben. Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen. [statement:{edited}, arguments:{edited}]
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1796)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultProducers.lambda$getResultSet$2(ResultProducers.java:64)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.lambda$of$0(ResultIterable.java:54)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.stream(ResultIterable.java:228)
    at db.DB.getProjectionData(DB.java:251)
    at server.api.ProjectionDataResource.getProjectionData(ProjectionDataResource.java:86)
    at server.api.ProjectionDataResource.lambda$getDs$0(ProjectionDataResource.java:104)
    at server.api.ZipStreamer.write(ZipStreamer.java:37)
    at server.api.StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.java:27)
    at server.api.StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.java:15)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:233)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:191)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.serialization.FixedEntityWriterArray.write(FixedEntityWriterArray.java:30)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:307)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:249)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:391)
        at server.api.ZipStreamer.write(ZipStreamer.java:35)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:116)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.writeBlocking(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:231)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:305)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:934)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:344)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:836)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute0(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:827)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:817)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.queueForWrite(ConnectionBase.java:236)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:226)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:216)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:212)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Http1xServerResponse.java:413)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Http1xServerResponse.java:393)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:107)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server hat keine Antwort zurückgegeben. Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3795)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6802)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:8015)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:618)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:540)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3912)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:518)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.execute(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:299)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlLoggerUtil.wrap(SqlLoggerUtil.java:31)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1788)
    ... 22 more

2023-02-10 21:17:06,032 ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) Request failed [Error Occurred After Shutdown]: org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server hat keine Antwort zurückgegeben. Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen. [statement:
{edited}, arguments:{edited}]
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1796)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultProducers.lambda$getResultSet$2(ResultProducers.java:64)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.lambda$of$0(ResultIterable.java:54)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.stream(ResultIterable.java:228)
    at db.DB.getProjectionData(DB.java:251)
    at server.api.ProjectionDataResource.getProjectionData(ProjectionDataResource.java:86)
    at server.api.ProjectionDataResource.lambda$getDs$0(ProjectionDataResource.java:104)
    at server.api.ZipStreamer.write(ZipStreamer.java:37)
    at server.api.StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.java:27)
    at server.api.StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamingOutputMessageBodyWriter.java:15)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:233)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:191)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.serialization.FixedEntityWriterArray.write(FixedEntityWriterArray.java:30)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:307)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:249)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:391)
        at server.api.ZipStreamer.write(ZipStreamer.java:35)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:116)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.writeBlocking(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:231)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:305)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:934)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:344)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:836)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute0(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:827)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:817)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.queueForWrite(ConnectionBase.java:236)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:226)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:216)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:212)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Http1xServerResponse.java:413)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Http1xServerResponse.java:393)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:107)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server hat keine Antwort zurückgegeben. Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3795)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6802)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:8015)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:618)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:540)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3912)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:518)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.execute(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:299)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlLoggerUtil.wrap(SqlLoggerUtil.java:31)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1788)
    ... 22 more

2023-02-10 21:17:06,033 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) data-access-service-quarkus stopped in 87.703s

Process finished with exit code 255
```